# What is the primitive of $\dfrac{1}{\sin x+1}$?

Tags: integration

I hope you are well
I try to find the infinite primitive of $\dfrac{1}{\sin x+1}$ without using the méthode of substituting by $\tan \frac x2$.

So I multiply and divide by $\sin x - 1$ and simplify until having
The result: $\tan x -\dfrac{1}{\cos x}$
But the professor said that my méthode is not totally correct because I can't divide by $1-\sin x$ because this expression can be null , so is there any methods except of the substitution using $\tan \frac x2$ to find this primitive?

Thank you for reading the question and for helping.

Comment: Use Mathjax to improve readability.

Comment: @HarishChandraRajpoot - It would be more helpful to give a [link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @mr_e_man Ok, thanks.

Comment: @wissal - Indeed, the integrand is defined for all $x\neq-\pi/2$ $(\bmod2\pi)$, but your result is not defined at $x=+\pi/2$, so it's not quite correct. However, setting aside these singular points, your result is equivalent to $-\cos(x)/(1+\sin(x))$, so I suggest finding a way to derive that directly.

Comment: Actually any solution involving $\tan(x/2)$ has the same problem, since that's undefined at $x=\pi$.

Answer (score 8):

Hint:
$$\frac{1}{\sin x+1}=\frac1{\cos(\frac\pi2-x)+1}=\frac1{2\cos^2(\frac\pi4-\frac x2)}= \frac12\sec^2(\frac\pi4-\frac x2)
$$

Comment: I don't know what the OP had in mind with $\tan(x/2)$, but your answer gives $\tan(x/2-\pi/4)$ so it's similar.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{1}{1+\sin x} d x & =\int \frac{1-\sin x}{\cos ^2 x} d x \\
& =\int \sec ^2 x d x-\int \sec x \tan x d x \\
& =\tan x-\sec x+C
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: But how to find (cos(x))^2?

Comment: $1-\sin^2x =\cos^2 x$, got it?

Comment: But you can't divide by 1-(sinx)^2 because it can equals to 0

Comment: This is exactly the "not totally correct" method suggested in the OP.